# MAMP pro PHP Error handling grief

Tags: php, mamp, localserver

So mamp pro is all set up using PHP 5.3.6 / cache is XCache, error handling set to Display Startup errors - write to All errors and warnings - to set to Display and Log both checked.

restart the server, intentionally wrote some code that should bring up an error..

```
<?php
   echo stupid;
?>
```

Yes this is all thats in the code.
I get nothing! No errors, only in the log. 
I don't want to have my console open the entire time watching for errors, I want them printed on the screen.

The only way I can get this to work is by doing an INCLUDE on this code at the top of EVERY SINGLE PHP file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
init-- yad yada ('display_errors', 'on');
```

From what I'm reading elsewhere, it seems like this is a big problem.. 
So how can I set up my mamp pro PHP.INI file to work properly and print directly to my browser?

Answer (score 1):

I changed it in MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini

You can change display_errors and display_startup_errors